# Subset of Imagenet Dataset for image classification

Tags: image, machine-learning, dataset, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I need an annotated dataset, **subset of Imagenet**, that includes square images of size: 224x224.

I tried Tiny Imagenet and Cifar-10, but they consist of quite smaller images and don't fit my needs.

Is there anything similar available? I cannot use the entire Imagenet dataset.

**Note:** Size doesn't have to be exact but similar.

Comment: Hey, did you find suitable dataset ?

Comment: @shivam.kotwalia I used VOC dataset.

Comment: Thanks, just another doubt, does VOC has same classes as Image-net. Because I want to compare all the existing Model (VGG, Resnet) !!

Comment: @ShivamKotwalia No it does not. It has only 21 (including background). I needed more generic classes, so this was not an issue in my case..

Comment: hey. can you provide your train.prototxt. I'm facing the same problem. I need to do classification for about 10 class of object. but i dont want the performace to be too low.

Comment: I need a subset of fruits and vegetables. I didn't find any yet. If you know there is one, please provide a link. Or if You know how to build the subset, please let me know

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the Imagenette and Imagewoof dataset. These two subsets of Imagenet were designed to be easy and hard to train on. https://github.com/fastai/imagenette

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tiny ImageNet which has 200 classes. Each class has 500 training images, 50 validation images, and 50 test images. 
https://tiny-imagenet.herokuapp.com/

Comment: The size of the Tiny ImageNet images is only 64 x 64 pixels.

Comment: it's not there anymore.

Comment: @thestruggleisreal :  Archive.org is great for finding old datasets; I was able to find a copy of the Tiny ImageNet dataset here: https://web.archive.org/web/20200710053839/https://tiny-imagenet.herokuapp.com/   Click on the green `Download Tiny ImageNet` button and you'll be prompted to download the zip file, or `wget` the zip file directly with this URL: https://web.archive.org/web/20200710053839/http://cs231n.stanford.edu/tiny-imagenet-200.zip